# `Command terminated` while using `cin`

Tags: c++, cin

I am using C++ 11 to write a simple code, but encountered `Command terminated` error if I put specific values.

The code is:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int r, c;
    cin >> r >> c;

    int **Data = new int*[r+2]();
    for(int i=0; i < c+2; i++){
        Data[i] = new int[c+2]();
    }

    // Input Data
    for(int n=1; n<r+1; n++){
        for(int m=1; m<c+1; m++){
            cin >> Data[n][m];
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This code works fine with most inputs, such as:

```
clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ test.cpp -o test.out
./test.out
2 2
1 2
3 4
```

However, if I put specific values, it clashes:

```
clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ test2.cpp -o test2.out
./test2.out
5 1
1
2
3

Command terminated
```

Why does this happen??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the wrong upper bound here:

```
for(int i=0; i < c+2; i++){
```

It should be:

```
for(int i=0; i < r+2; i++){
```